# Self intersection of degree $d$ plane curves in $\mathbb P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a nonsingular degree $d$ plane curve  in $\mathbb P^3$ over complex numbers. My interest is to calculate self-intersection of $C$. Does the following calculation make sense?

From adjunction formula we know that if $C$ is a non-singular curve of genus $g$ on $\mathbb P^2$ and if $K$ is the canonical divisor of $\mathbb P^2$, then $2g-2=C.(C+K)$. We know that $g= \frac{1}{2}(d-1)(d-2)$ and as $K \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(-3)$ we have, $(d-1)(d-2) -2 =C^2 -3d $. Which means $C^2=d^2$ .

But I am nowhere using that the entire phenomenon is happening inside $\mathbb P^3$. Am I missing something very obvious?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: You made an algebraic error at the last step; you should get $C^2 = d^2$.

Comment: @TabesBridges, thanks, I have edited now. But is there any other conceptual error?

Comment: As the answer notes, two curves in $\mathbb P^3$ have $0$ intersection. Formally, this is because the Chow ring of $\mathbb P^3$ vanishes above $A^3$, so the map $A^2 \times A^2 \to A^4$ is the zero map. Geometrically, this is because two cubics in the same plane ($C \cap H$ and $C' \cap H$ for $C,C'$ cubic surfaces and $H$ a plane) can be deformed to two cubics in different planes ($C\cap H$ and $C' \cap H'$) which obviously fail to intersect for generic choices...

Comment: ...What you are interested in I guess is that associativity of the intersection product tells us that the intersection of two cubic surfaces in a degree $9$ curve $C\cap C'$ which then intersects a general plane $H$ in $9$ points, is in some sense "the same" as the intersection of a cubic surface and a plane (producing a plane cubic $C \cap H$) with another cubic surface $C'$ (since the second cubic surface traces out a second plane cubic).

Comment: @TabesBridges, If these intersections are always zero, then In the comment to the following question in MO https://mathoverflow.net/q/382139   how are we getting $D^2=-10$? Is something else is meant there in the comment?

Comment: That computation is taking place in the Chow ring of $X$, which is a surface in $\mathbb P^3$. The corresponding intersection number in $A^*(\mathbb P^3)$ would be $D^2.X$.

Comment: @TabesBridges, In that case what is $A^2.X$ ?is it $24$? I think not. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I don't understand. I'm using $A$ here to denote the Chow ring. You mean what is $D^2.X$? That would be $-10$; I'm just saying that if we assume that $D$ is the restriction to $X$ of a surface in $\mathbb P^3$, which may or may not be true, then the intersection number on $X$ could also be computed as an intersection number on $\mathbb P^3$.

Comment: @Tabes Bridges, there it was $D=A+B$ ...sum of two divisors. In that context I was talking about $A^2$

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you were still referring to the link. Well by adjunction the sextic surface $X$ has $K_X \equiv 2H|_X$ with $H$ the hyperplane section. Now using adjunction on $A$ we get $\deg(K_A) = K_X.A + A^2$. The left hand side is $-2$ since $A$ is rational, and $A \equiv K_X \equiv 2H$ so $K_X.A = 4$ hence $A^2 = -6$. Since $\deg(K_B)=0$ but $K_X.B=6$, we also have $B^2=6$. Since by construction $A.B=1$ we conclude $D^2 = -10$.

Comment: @TabesBridges, Thanks. Just out of curiosity I have one more question: whatever they are mentioning there as $C$, you are mentioning it here as $H$ right? then $2C-D \equiv 2H-D \equiv 2H-A-B \equiv -B$ and therefore the linear system $|2C-D|$ is empty right?

Comment: Sorry, yes. The hyperplane section that I habitually write as $H$ was called $C$ in the linked post, and your argument that $|2C-D| = \emptyset$ seems perfectly fine.

Comment: @TabesBridges, thanks. But there in that post it was supposed to be a counterexample i.e it was supposed to give the linear system $|2C-D|$ to be non-empty, right?

Comment: Yes, and in retrospect I'm not sure what I was thinking when I said I followed your argument. How are you getting $2H-A-B\equiv -B$? This boils down to $2H\equiv A$, but a smooth curve in $|2H|$ has degree $12$, not $2$. And the indicated non-emptiness is by construction: because the two planes used in that construction furnish a section of $2H$ containing $D$, the residual curve of degree $7$ gives an explicit section of $2H-D$.

Comment: @TabesBridges thanks.

Comment: @TabesBridges, I was going through this post. Could you please explain your last comment about the residual curve of degree $7$  giving an explicit section of $2H-D$. Is there a more short exact sequence way to see that $h^0(\mathcal O_X(2H-D)) \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (in the sense of intersection theory) is always $0$.  In general, the intersection of a codimension $d$ cycle and a codimension $e$ cycle has codimension $d+e$.  In the case of curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$, they are codimension $2$, so their intersection has codimension $4$, i.e. it is a cycle of dimension $-1$, which just means it is automatically $0$.

Comment: ,If $C$ is a hyperplane section of a smooth surface of degree $d \geq 4$ in $\mathbb P^3$, then it's a plane curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^3$, then we know that $C^2=d$, right?